# what is the difference between a simple commit and conventional commit

Tags: git, conventional-commits

I'm new with the git and i'm working on my own project and what i do every time is

```
git add .
```

then

```
git commit -m "message "
```

with a message and then i push but recently i learnt about commit conventional but i didn't understand what is the difference about them ? can u explain it to me I mean i search for method that allows my friend to be updated and understand what i do on my project  thanks on advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/) is purely a convention of how to structure the commit message.

It's probably not hugely important if it's just you and a few friends (at least not more important than the actual message text), but in bigger projects and projects with lots of public interest and/or automated tools working on them it's a unified way to structure frequently-provided information.

For example if your commit message would usually be something like

```
Add option to frobnicate the quux.
```

Then the "equivalent" commit message written to the rules of a Conventional Commits would look something like this:

```
feat(quux): Add option to frobnicate the quux.

Refs: FOO-123
```

(Where `FOO-123` would be a reference to some ticketing system).

As you see it's not fundamentally different, it just provides a fixed structure and some conventions.

In my opinion as long as you don't strictly use tickets (bugs/issues/...) to track all your work, you're probably not at a level where you need to care about this.

Comment: The `Refs: FOO-123` seems irrelevant. The “trailer” part (what conventional commits calls “footers”) predates conventional commits as a built-in git(1) “convention”. It’s also optional unlike the structure of the subject/header.